# Simplifying a nested list without for loops

Tags: r, list

I have a list (imported from an API JSON) with a complex and nested structure that I need to tidy. I only manage to do it with for loops, which does not seem optimal : lengthy to write, long to compute with many elements and possible errors if new variations appear. Is there a way to obtain a similar results with tidyverse functions such as `map()`, `unnnest()`,  `flatten()`, `squash()` or equivalents in base R? I haven't found any example in StackOverflow with similar combination of issues (pointed below the example).
Here is the reproducible example :

```
metadata <- list(
  table1 = list(
    attribute1 = "tb1_att1",
    level_to_disard = list(
      attribute2 = "tb1_att2",
      columns = list(
        column1 = list(
          col_name = "tb1_col1_name",
          col_type = "tb1_col1_type"
        ),
        column2 = list(
          col_name = "tb1_col2_name",
          col_type = "tb1_col2_type"
        )
      ),
      tags = c("tag1", "tag2", "tag3"),
      irrelevant = list(irrelveant1 = "blabla", irrelevant2 = "blibli")
    )
  ),
  table2 = list(
    attribute1 = "tb2_att1",
    level_to_disard = list(
      columns = list(
        column1 = list(
          col_name = "tb2_col1_name",
          col_irrelevant = "bloblo"
        ),
        column2 = list(
          col_name = "tb2_col2_name",
          col_type = "tb2_col2_type"
        )
      ),
      tags = c("tag1", "tag3")
    )
  )
)

str(metadata)
# Output in console:
List of 2
 $ table1:List of 2
  ..$ attribute1     : chr "tb1_att1"
  ..$ level_to_disard:List of 4
  .. ..$ attribute2: chr "tb1_att2"
  .. ..$ columns   :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ column1:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ col_name: chr "tb1_col1_name"
  .. .. .. ..$ col_type: chr "tb1_col1_type"
  .. .. ..$ column2:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ col_name: chr "tb1_col2_name"
  .. .. .. ..$ col_type: chr "tb1_col1_type"
  .. ..$ tags      : chr [1:3] "tag1" "tag2" "tag3"
  .. ..$ irrelevant:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ irrelveant1: chr "blabla"
  .. .. ..$ irrelevant2: chr "blibli"
 $ table2:List of 2
  ..$ attribute1     : chr "tb2_att1"
  ..$ level_to_disard:List of 2
  .. ..$ columns:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ column1:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ col_name      : chr "tb2_col1_name"
  .. .. .. ..$ col_irrelevant: chr "bloblo"
  .. .. ..$ column2:List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ col_name: chr "tb2_col2_name"
  .. .. .. ..$ col_type: chr "tb2_col1_type"
  .. ..$ tags   : chr [1:2] "tag1" "tag3"
```

Note that attributes are located at different levels, some elements (named 'irrelevant' in the list) must be discarded, 'attribute2' is missing from table 2 and 'type' is missing for column 1 of table 2.
Here is the solution with for loops and the expected result.

```
# Define a function to extract column information
extract_cols <- function(x){
  fields <- tibble()
  if (length(x) == 0) {
    return(fields)
  } else {
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
      fields <- add_row(fields)
      # Extract name
      fields$name[i] = ""
      # Extract type if present of return empty string
      if (any(names(x[[i]]) == "type")) {
        fields$type[i] = x[[i]][["type"]]
      } else {
        fields$type[i] = ""
      }
      return(fields)
    }
  }
}

# Create an empty tibble for the tidy metadata. It could also be a list.
library(tibble)
meta <- tibble()

# for (i in 1:1) {
 for (i in 1:length(metadata)) {
  meta <- add_row(meta)
  meta$attribute1[[i]] <- metadata[[i]][["attribute1"]]
  meta$attribute2[[i]] <- ifelse(length(metadata[[i]][["level_to_disard"]][["attribute2"]]) > 0,
                          c(metadata[[i]][["level_to_disard"]][["attribute2"]]), "")
    metadata[[i]][["level_to_disard"]][["attribute2"]]
  meta$cols[[i]] <- extract_cols(metadata[[i]][["columns"]])
  meta$tags[[i]] <- metadata[[i]][["level_to_disard"]][["tags"]]

}
str(meta)
# Output in console:
tibble [2 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ attribute1: chr [1:2] "tb1_att1" "tb2_att1"
 $ attribute2: chr [1:2] "tb1_att2" ""
 $ cols      :List of 2
  ..$ : tibble [0 × 0] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 Named list()
  ..$ : tibble [0 × 0] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 Named list()
 $ tags      :List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "tag1" "tag2" "tag3"
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "tag1" "tag3"
```

Is there a more straightforward way to obtain this result? The output could be a list, a tibble or a dataframe, as long as it is simplified with a similar structure than 'meta'`enter code here` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tidyverse`:
I have added comments for steps to make it more readable.

```
df<- unlist(metadata) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% # unlist and changing to data.frame
  rownames_to_column() %>% #adding row names to data
  magrittr::set_colnames(c("Var","value")) %>% #renaming columns
  tidyr::separate('Var', paste("Tag", 1:5, sep="_"), sep="[.]", extra="drop") %>% #spliting column to get all levels
  dplyr::mutate(Level1= ifelse(grepl("attribute",Tag_2)|grepl("attribute",Tag_3), "attribute",paste0(Tag_2,"_",Tag_3)),
                Level1= gsub("\\d.*", "", Level1),
                Level2=paste0(Level1,"_",Tag_5),
                Level2= gsub("_NA*", "", Level2)
                ) %>% #cleaning of data based on patterns to reach clean levels
  ungroup()%>%
  dplyr::group_by(Tag_1,Level2) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(n= row_number()) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Level2=paste0(Level2,n),
               Level3= ifelse(Level1=="attribute",Level1,Level2),
               Level4= ifelse(is.na(Tag_5),Level1,Tag_5),
               Level4= gsub("level_to_disard_","",Level4),
               Level1= gsub("level_to_disard_","",Level1),
               Level5= ifelse(Level1=="attribute",Level2,Level1)
               ) %>% #cleaning again based on patterns to reach clean levels
  dplyr::select(Tag_1,Level1,Level2,Level3,Level4,Level5,value) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Tag_1,Level5) %>% # at this step you can change Level number to get data at any other level
  dplyr::mutate(value_1=paste0(value,collapse = ",")) %>%
  dplyr::select(Tag_1,Level5,value_1) %>%
  dplyr::distinct() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from =c(Level5),values_from =  value_1) # changing to wide format
```

`output:`

```
df
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   Tag_1 [2]
  Tag_1  attribute1 attribute2 columns                                                 tags           irrelevant   
  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>                                                   <chr>          <chr>        
1 table1 tb1_att1   tb1_att2   tb1_col1_name,tb1_col1_type,tb1_col2_name,tb1_col2_type tag1,tag2,tag3 blabla,blibli
2 table2 tb2_att1   NA         tb2_col1_name,bloblo,tb2_col2_name,tb2_col2_type        tag1,tag3      NA
```

You can drop columns which are not required using `select`.

Comment: Wow! This approach based on unlisting and fetching and parsing rownames is very different to what I had imagined and it works quite well. Bravo! One remaining issue is  to tidy the nested column information. But it essentially fits the objective.Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. If my suggestion suitably answers your question, click the tick mark to accept it as the chosen answer and upvote it. could you explain more  on tidy issue

Comment: I accepted right away and upvoted now (my upvote was only registered and not displayed, as I don't have enough rep for that on SO). Regarding the "tidy issue", I meant that in the for loop solution, only specific column attributes are retrieved (name and type), discarding irrrelevant information ("bloblo"). But I see that your solution works also if only, instead of having `columns` at level 5, I pass Level 4 attributes of columns (`col_name`, `col_type` and `col_irrelevant`) to Level 5.